# Can it possible to get log before print the logcat?

Tags: android, logging

Can it possible to get the logs before it print into terminal? Or I want to know how the crash crashlytics takes logs.

Comment: it registers global exceptions handler, and catches all the exceptions before the app is crashed (**probably**. Only crashlytics developers can tell you for sure)

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics doesn't have anything to do with the log system.  It hooks the top level exception handler, so that exceptions that are not handled by the program normally are handled by the library.

Comment: Can give me some idea how it hooks the top level exception?